# How do I add a Column to my Group By statement?

Tags: sql

```
select 
    dumb1.court#, court1.courtname, count(judgename) as "number of judges"
from 
    labdatas18.court court1 
left join 
    labdatas18.judge on court1.court# = labdatas18.judge.court#
inner join 
    labdatas18.court dumb1 on dumb1.court# = court1.court#
group by 
    court1.courtname;
```

How do I add `dumb1.court#` to my group by?

Comment: `Group by dumb1.court#, court1.courtname`

Comment: It appears to me that the join to `labdatas18.court` is unnecessary as everything you need is in the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dumb1.court#, court1.courtname, count(judgename) as "number of judges"

from labdatas18.court court1 left join labdatas18.judge

on court1.court# = labdatas18.judge.court#

inner join labdatas18.court dumb1

on dumb1.court# = court1.court#

Group by dumb1.court#, court1.courtname;
```